# Kotlin code reports "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, listview, gridview

I am making a Kotlin project using a few functionalities

What the code does is as follows -

1. Take a username from spinner
2. Takes the title of the budget from the radio buttons

It navigates to another page after displaying a toast message

Upon entering the required fields there are three buttons which do the following -

1. Upon clicking button1, there is a toast message displaying the total cost
2. Upon clicking button2, it displays an alert dialog stating whether the budget is greater than expenditure of vice-versa
3. Redirects to a new page with a listview and gridview

I am facing the following error -

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
<init>(Context, Int, Int, Array<(out) TypeVariable(T)!>)   where T = TypeVariable(T) for    constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(context: Context, resource: Int, textViewResourceId: Int, objects: Array<(out) T!>) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter
<init>(Context, Int, Int, (Mutable)List<TypeVariable(T)!>)   where T = TypeVariable(T) for    constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(context: Context, resource: Int, textViewResourceId: Int, objects: (Mutable)List<T!>) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter
```

I am new to Kotlin.

Here is the code:

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.b1_midsemquestion

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.*
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var selectedthing: String
    private lateinit var selectedItem: String
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        //spinner
        var spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinner)
        var spinnerArray = arrayOf("Ayush","Piyush","Random")
        val spinneradapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,spinnerArray)
        spinneradapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        spinner.adapter = spinneradapter
        spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            }
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
            }
        }
        //spinner
        var radiogroup = findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.radiogrp)
        var submit = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        submit.setOnClickListener {
            val selectedRadioButtonId: Int = radiogroup.checkedRadioButtonId
            if(selectedRadioButtonId != -1) {
                var selectedRadioButton = findViewById<RadioButton>(selectedRadioButtonId)
                selectedthing = selectedRadioButton.text.toString();

            }
            //toast message
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "$selectedthing is selected by $selectedItem",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            //toast message
            //intent
            var intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,SecondActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("key",selectedItem)
            intent.putExtra("key2",selectedthing)
            startActivity(intent)
            //intent

        }
        }



    }
```

SecondActivity.kt

```
package com.example.b1_midsemquestion



import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.*
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var selectedthing:String;

    //alert dialog

    //alert dialog
    fun showAlert(context: Context, title: String, message: String) {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        builder.setTitle(title)
        builder.setMessage(message)
        var textview: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView4)
        textview.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, _ ->
            textview.text = "Ok Pressed";
            textview.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
        val dialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity)
        var user = intent.getStringExtra("key")
        var expense = intent.getStringExtra("key2")
        var heading = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView2)
        heading.text = expense.toString();
        var budget = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.budget)
        var button1 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
        var button2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button3)
        var radiogrp2 = findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.radiogrp2)
        var button3 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button4)
        var quantity = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.quantity)
        var price = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.price)
        var foodcost = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.foodcost)
        var transcost = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.transcost)
        var train = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkBox)
        var taxi = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkBox3)
        var flight = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkBox4)
        button1.setOnClickListener {
            var quantityval = quantity.text.toString();
            val quantityint = quantityval.toInt();
            var priceval = price.text.toString();
            val priceint = priceval.toInt();
            var transval = transcost.text.toString();
            val transint = transval.toInt();
            var foodval = foodcost.text.toString();
            val foodint = foodval.toInt();

            val totalcost = quantityint*priceint + foodint + transint;
            Toast.makeText(this@SecondActivity,"Total cost is $totalcost ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        button2.setOnClickListener {
            var quantityval = quantity.text.toString();
            val quantityint = quantityval.toInt();
            var priceval = price.text.toString();
            val priceint = priceval.toInt();
            var transval = transcost.text.toString();
            val transint = transval.toInt();
            var foodval = foodcost.text.toString();
            val foodint = foodval.toInt();
            val totalcost = quantityint*priceint + foodint + transint;
            var budgetval = budget.text.toString();
            val budgetint = budgetval.toInt();
            if(totalcost > budgetint) {
                //alertdialog

                    showAlert(this,"Alert", "Total cost greater than budget")

                //alertdialog
            }
            else {

                    showAlert(this,"Alert", "Budget is greater than the total cost")

            }
        }
        button3.setOnClickListener {
            var intent2 = Intent(this@SecondActivity,ThirdActivity::class.java)
            var checkselected = "";
            var trainselected = "";
            var flightselected = "";
            var taxiselected = "";
            //checkboxes
            if(train.isChecked()) {
                trainselected = "train";
            }
            if(flight.isChecked()) {
                flightselected = "flight";
            }
            if(taxi.isChecked()) {
                taxiselected = "taxi";
            }
            //checkboxes
            intent2.putExtra("train",trainselected)
            //puting extra into intent
            intent2.putExtra("flight",flightselected)
            intent2.putExtra("taxi",taxiselected)

            //radiobutton
            val selectedRadioButtonId: Int = radiogrp2.checkedRadioButtonId
            if(selectedRadioButtonId != -1) {
                var selectedRadioButton = findViewById<RadioButton>(selectedRadioButtonId)
                selectedthing = selectedRadioButton.text.toString();

            }
            //radiobutton
            intent2.putExtra("key4", selectedthing)

            startActivity(intent2)

        }

    }
}
```

ThirdActivity.kt

```
package com.example.b1_midsemquestion



import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.*
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat


class ThirdActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.third_activity)
        var listview = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listview)
        var train = intent.getStringExtra("train")
        var flight = intent.getStringExtra("flight")
        var taxi = intent.getStringExtra("taxi")
        var selectedthing = intent.getStringExtra("key4")

        var values = arrayOf(train,flight,taxi,selectedthing)

        //listview
        val listadapter = ArrayAdapter(
            this@ThirdActivity,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            values
        )
        listview.adapter = listadapter;
        listview.setOnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
            val selecteditem = values[position]
            Toast.makeText(this, "Item selected is $selecteditem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        //listview


        //gridview
        var gridview = findViewById<GridView>(R.id.gridview)
        var items = arrayOf("ayush", "piyush", "random", "newone")
       var gridadapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_layout, items, R.id.textView5)
        gridview.adapter = gridadapter;
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
            val selecteditem = items[position]
            val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel_id")
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_chat)
                .setContentTitle("Selected Item")
                .setContentText("You have selected $selecteditem")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

            // Create a notification manager object
            val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

            // Check if the device is running Android Oreo or higher
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                // Create a notification channel
                val channel = NotificationChannel("channel_id", "Channel Name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
                channel.description = "Channel Description"
                // Register the channel with the system
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
            }
            // Issue the notification
            notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build())
        }
        //gridview





    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem top be multiple issues , I seperated your code into parts

SPINNER

```
package com.example.spinner

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Spinner
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var options = arrayOf("verna","harrier","duster")
        val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinner)
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,options)
        var f1 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextText)
        var f2 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
        spinner.adapter = adapter
        spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
            override fun onItemSelected(
                parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                view: View?,
                position: Int,
                id: Long
            ) {
                var selectedItem = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,selectedItem,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                f1.setText(selectedItem)
                f2.setText(selectedItem)
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

LISTVIEW

```
package com.example.listview

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ListView
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var cheezen = arrayOf("Hey","Yo","Wow")
        var ls = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listview1)
        var f1 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
        var adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,cheezen)
        ls.adapter = adapter

        ls.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
            val selecteItem = cheezen[position]
            f1.setText(selecteItem)
        }
    }
}
```

---

GRIDVIEW INTENT

```
package com.example.gridview2

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.GridView
import android.widget.Toast

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var gridView = findViewById<GridView>(R.id.gridView)
        var items = arrayOf("verna","harrier","duster","i10")
        var gridadapter = ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.grid_item_layout,R.id.textView,items)
        gridView.adapter = gridadapter

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
            val selecteditem = items[position]
            val intent = Intent(this,SecondActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("key",selecteditem)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

SECOND ACT

```
package com.example.gridview2

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.GridView
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast

class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity)
        var item = intent.getStringExtra("key")
        var f1 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView2)
        f1.setText(item)
    }
}
```

Manifest - `<activity android:name=".SecondActivity"/>`

---

ALERT DIALOG

```
package com.example.alertdialog

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    fun showalert(context: Context,title:String,message: String){
        var alert = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("Move") { dialog, which ->
                var intent = Intent(this,SecondActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("key",message)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel"){ dialog , which ->

            }
            .create()
        alert.show()
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var f1 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextText)
        var btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        btn.setOnClickListener {
            showalert(this,"Button pressed","you have written "+f1.text)

        }
    }
}
```

---

INVISIBLE

```
package com.example.visibility

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var btn = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton)
        var text = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.lol1)
        btn.setOnClickListener{
            if(text.visibility == View.VISIBLE){
                text.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
            else{
                text.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

RADIO CHECKBOX

```
package com.example.radiocheck

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.CheckBox
import android.widget.RadioButton
import android.widget.RadioGroup
import android.widget.Toast

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var radiogrp = findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.rad1)
        var btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        var checkbox = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkBox)
        var checkbox2 = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkBox2)
        var btn2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
        var selecteditem = findViewById<RadioButton>(R.id.radioButton3)
        radiogrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
            selecteditem = findViewById<RadioButton>(checkedId)

        }
        btn.setOnClickListener {
            if(checkbox2.isChecked && checkbox.isChecked){
                Toast.makeText(this,"School ,College Done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            else if(checkbox.isChecked){
                Toast.makeText(this,"School Done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            else if(checkbox2.isChecked){
                Toast.makeText(this,"College Done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }


        }
        btn2.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this,selecteditem.text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    }
}
```

---

GRIDVIEW + NOTIFICATION

```
package com.example.gridview3

import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.GridView
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var gridview = findViewById<GridView>(R.id.gv)
        var items = arrayOf("ayush", "piyush", "random", "newone")
        var gridadapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_layout, R.id.textView, items)
        gridview.adapter = gridadapter;
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
            val selecteditem = items[position]
            val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel_id")
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_chat)
                .setContentTitle("Selected Item")
                .setContentText("You have selected $selecteditem")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

            // Create a notification manager object
            val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

            // Check if the device is running Android Oreo or higher
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                // Create a notification channel
                val channel = NotificationChannel("channel_id", "Channel Name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
                channel.description = "Channel Description"
                // Register the channel with the system
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
            }
            // Issue the notification
            notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build())
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have made a mistake on this line in the ThirdActivity.kt

var gridadapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_layout, items, R.id.textView5)

The syntax should be

var gridadapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_layout, R.id.textView5, items)

instead

R.id.textView5 should come before items

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).